# How to put text in time series chart in Flot?

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a real time updating time series chart very similar to this [one](http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-ajax-update-chart.html). How can I add some text to the chart starting at a certain time and it moves along with the chart? I am designating a time range in the chart as belonging to a certain condition and the text is used for this. Is there a Flot plugin which can be used?

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer should help you and I threw together this fiddle that I think answers your question.

[jQuery/Flot: How do you get the coordinates of a datapoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964798/jquery-flot-how-do-you-get-the-coordinates-of-a-datapoint)

```
for(var k = 0; k < points.length; k++){
      for(var m = 0; m < points[k].data.length; m++){
        showTooltip(graphx + points[k].xaxis.p2c(points[k].data[m][0]), graphy + points[k].yaxis.p2c(points[k].data[m][1]),points[k].data[m][1])
        }
  }
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g3dzp/1/

Comment: It's not a legend. Legend stays fixed in place.